# Custom TimePicker in order to reduce its size

Tags: android, resize, size, timepicker

All I would like to do is reduce the size of the default TimePicker, however I have been unsuccessful with this. So - I have created a custom TimePicker, ie I have a class that derives from TimePicker (call it TimePickerCustom), and an XML file that has exactly the same contents as the original TimePicker (except I plan to make the NumberPicker sizes smaller).

I need to define one of the constructors that have AttributeSet as a parameter in my TimePickerCustom, in order to inflate the XML properly, and of course I need to call the parent class' constructor for this in here. The problem is, that these constructors inflate the original TimePicker xml, so I still see the default TimePicker widget!

How should I set this up so that I can see only my custom TimePicker widget? Or is there another way to simply reduce the size of the default TimePicker?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the parent's layout inflation by calling the non-inflating parent constructor. For example:

```
public TimePickerCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context);
    // custom layout // getLayoutInflater().inflate(...
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but there's a ton of initialization stuff that happens in the parent class's inflating constructor ie TimePicker(Context, AttributeSet, int). I can copy and paste what I need from here, but the members it accesses here are private, so my subclass doesn't have access to them.

Comment: Ah, welcome to the club. You might need to go whole hog and start with the source for TimePicker instead of subclassing it. Even then, you'll still be unable to access certain members from other superclasses. E.g., I tweaked the ScrollView code and had to replace uses of mScrollY with getScrollY().

Comment: oh that sucks! you're right, I can't seem to access everything, for instance, TimePicker uses NumberPicker, however I can't seem to access this. Okay, thanks for your help!